# android, imageview stretch

Tags: android, imageview

I'm trying to get my imageview with a drawable png to fill the display (I don't care about ratios). However, fill_parent doesn't work, and as far as I know there are no background to be set to a RelativeLayout?

Regards

```
RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:onClick="toggleAdvice"



   ImageView
    android:id="@+id/advice_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/pratbubbla_gron"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

Comment: can you paste your XML Layout code here?

Comment: remove this android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" and try with layout_gravity:"center"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used to stretch/shring ImageView programmatically, probably this piece of code will help you:

```
    ImageView imageView=new ImageView(context);
    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    imageView.setMaxHeight(maxHeight);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    layout.addView(imageView);
```

Answer (score 8):

All View types have `android:background`, including `RelativeLayout`. No need for an `ImageView`, although I can't see any reason for your one to not fill the parent.

Comment: Like Reuben, I used the background instead of the src and that seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

to do it in code use:
            yourImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

Comment: This is the one that worked for me, the others did not stretch the image, this one will.